# Computation of differentiation of Bessel function in matlab

Tags: matlab, differentiation, bessel-functions

In Matlab, why do differentiation of Bessel function j1(x) for let us say x= 1:10 gives 9 values instead of 10?

```
x=1:10

J = besselj(1,x)

d_J = diff(J)

x =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10


J =

  Columns 1 through 7

    0.4401    0.5767    0.3391   -0.0660   -0.3276   -0.2767   -0.0047

  Columns 8 through 10

    0.2346    0.2453    0.0435


d_J =

  Columns 1 through 7

    0.1367   -0.2377   -0.4051   -0.2615    0.0509    0.2720    0.2393

  Columns 8 through 9

    0.0107   -0.2018
```

Comment: Read doc on [diff](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) ?

Comment: Because `diff` just computes _differences_ between consecutive values. The number of differences is one less than the number of values. Of course, you can use those differences to approximate the _derivative_ of the function, which is perhaps what you want.

Comment: Please pay attention to proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) applied *on a numerical vector* just computes **differences** between consecutive values. The number of differences is one less than the number of values. Of course, you can use those differences to numerically approximate the derivative of the function.

If you want to **compute the derivative** directly, you can do it with **symbolic computation** (see [Matlab Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.es/products/symbolic/)). When applied *on a symbolic function*, `diff` [does give you the derivative](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/diff.html):

```
>> syms x; %// define symbolic variable
>> f = besselj(1,x); %// define symbolic function
>> g = diff(f ,x) %// compute derivative
g =
besselj(0, x) - besselj(1, x)/x
```

You can then evaluate the derivative at specific values using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
>> subs(g, 1:8)
ans =
    0.3251   -0.0645   -0.3731   -0.3806   -0.1121    0.1968    0.3007    0.1423
```

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate a function numerically, you should use smaller steps and the `gradient` function:

```
x = 1:0.01:10;
J = besselj(1,x);
dJ = gradient(J,x);  % or: dJ = gradient(J)./gradient(x);
plot(x,J,x,dJ)
```

The second numerical derivative can be obtained with

```
dJ2 = 4*del2(J,x);  % or: dJ2 = 4*del2(J)./gradient(x).^2;
plot(x,J,x,dJ,x,dJ2)
```